# yum install (but where is the file)

Tags: ssh, installation, yum, tesseract

Ok so I install a software with yum install tesseract
tesseract being the software I wanted to install.

However it seems that the software is un-findable

Would anyone be able to tell me where CentOS stores software when using the yum install function, as I tried to look in usr/bin and it was not there

as well as I used the find .-name "tesseract*"

and nothing was found

however  i know it is installed

```
    [root@host ~]# yum install tesseract
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
addons                                                                                                          |  951 B     00:00     
base                                                                                                            | 1.1 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                          | 2.1 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                         | 1.9 kB     00:00     
wiredtree                                                                                                       |  951 B     00:00     
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Package tesseract-1.03-1.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps superuser.com or serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# rpm -qil tesseract
```

It will give you list of all the files that were installed from the package.